# When developing a chrome extension how can I open a blank page to run a script on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension that needs to open a blank page and then depending upon some injected script open 1/2 iframes inside this blank window.

My issue is how do I open a blank window that I can inject and run JS from?

I have attempted this by opening a page with the url of `about:blank` but I can not inject the script onto this page because of the following error:

```
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: 'about:blank'
}, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'jquery/jquery.js'
    }, function() {
        console.log('done', arguments);
    });
});

tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "about:blank".
Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

Obviously this error message makes me think that I don't have permission to access this url and updated my manifest to allow access to all urls but I have the same issue.

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "*://*/*"
],
```

---

### Extra Info

The reason why I am not opening a url directly is because I have 2 urls that I need to access one after the other. These files are upgrade scripts that I will need to see the results from.

The best way to do this would be to open a page and have an iframe of the left and right hand sides of the window that I can control using my injected script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make a dummy upgrade page in your extension's package, lets call it upgrade.html

use it to make your structure and add the 2 iframes that you want. 
If you want to control it, you can use message passing using a background script to communicate between 2 javascript pages. To communicate from parent page to iframe, just look at any answer in [Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page/7938270#7938270)

If you don't know the logic that you want to run beforehand - although you should - then you can just pass along whole strings between the pages and and eval them on the other side - although this is not something you generally want to do. Here's the docs for message passing: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html

---

In a nutshell: you have page A with your contentscript, page B is your background page and page C is the update page with the 2 iframes, then:

```
// A.js
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "content-script"});
port.postMessage({ runScript: 'yahoo(); function yahoo; () { alert("Yahoo!"); }' });

// B.js
// The background page is only used as a proxy
var upgrade_port = null;
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  switch (port.name) {
    case 'content-script':
       // Also you need to query for the upgrade page and open it if it does not exist
       port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
         upgrade_port.sendMessage(msg);
       });
       break;
    case 'upgrade-page':
      upgrade_port = port;
      break;
    default:
      console.warn('Unknown port name: ' + port.name);
  }
});

// C.js
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "upgrade-page"});
port.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
  if (message.runScript) {
    eval(message.runScript);
  }
});
```

---

You need to use port otherwise you can't communicate from one page to the other. Also, it's a lot better if you just insert the JS in page C beforehand and have it static and just pass along the arguments to the functions RPC-style (Remote Procedural Call), aka:

```
// A.js
port.postMessage({action:'RPC', name:'yahoo', args:['hello', 'world', 3]});

// C.js
var RPCs = {
  yahoo: function (str1, str2, no) {
    alert(str1 + ',\n' + str2 + '\nThis is a number: ' + no);
  }
};

port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
  switch (msg.action) {
    case 'RPC':
      if (!RPC[msg.name]) { console.warn('Unknown RPC: ' + msg.name); return; }
      RPC[msg.name].apply(RPC, msg.args || []);
      break;
    default:
      console.warn('Unknown action: ' + msg.action);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the biggest help for me was the realization that I can open a html page from my extension. That allows me to completely control it in the ways that I need